# Android Studio Displaying to log error

Tags: android, logging, message

I am trying to display a message to the log in android studio. I use Log.d(), but it gives me this error: Cannot resolve method d(). I find it strange because I used it before. Maybe I am missing something obvious.

Answer (score 0):

Try something like:

```
Log.d("DEBUG", "Some Text");
```

Log.d stands for Debug. Make sure you also import the Log class.

```
import android.util.Log;
```

You can also import it automatically by holding alt key with enter.

Check this: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/util/Log.html

Comment: I am afraid it didn't help. This is what I am importing: import sun.rmi.runtime.Log;     and this is the line of code: Log.d("DEBUG", Gdx.input.getX());

Comment: That's why it didn't work. Updated the answer. Check it. :)

Comment: Remove "import sun.rmi.runtime.Log;" and replace it with "import android.util.Log;"

Comment: Try to rebuild and clean your project. In the toolbar above, click on Build then Clean Project then once again Rebuild Project.

Comment: It is the same. If this helps you, this is another error it throws me: error: package android.util does not exist

Comment: Sorry man. I don't know why that happens but that should have worked. Try to remove the import statement of the log and import it manually by holding alt key with enter.